# I do not know where I went wrong?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals, partial-fractions

I was doing a question in which one step included solving this integral

$$
\int \frac{t}{\cos^2 t}\,dt
$$

So what book did was 
$$
          \int t\sec^2 t\,dt
$$

And then applied integration by parts .

Whereas what I did was 
$$
          \int  \frac{t} {1-\sin^2t}\, dt
$$

$$
          \int\frac{t}{(1+ \sin t)(1- \sin t)}\, dt
$$

And then using partial fraction .
$$
          \frac{A}{1+ \sin t}  + \frac{B}{1-\sin t}   = t
$$

$A = \frac{3\pi}{4}$  and 
$B = \frac{\pi}{4}$

Which when put in 
$$
          \frac{A}{1+ \sin t}  + \frac{B}{1-\sin t}   = t
$$
it did not satisfy the equation.

Which I think means that the values of $A$ and $B$ are incorrect.

So could someone tell where I went wrong?

Comment: Well, for $t=0$, the value of $A/(1+\sin t)+B/(1-\sin t)$ is $A+B$ and your choice of $A$ and $B$ gives $\pi$, which is quite different from $0$, isn't it? `;-)`

Comment: @egreg But why does this happen ?

Comment: Partial fraction decomposition is for rational functions (quotients of polynomials). In your case there is a trigonometric function in the denominator.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre Exactly , that's what even I was also thinking . Thank you .

Comment: you cannot use PFD in this way, so if you check this decomposition it is not true continuously for many values

Comment: @HenryLee What do you mean by *"in this way"* ?

Comment: There are no values for which it is true, normally this method only works with real number polynomial functions

Answer (score 3):

There are no constants $A$ and $B$ such that $\frac A {1+\sin t} +\frac B {1-\sin t}=t$ so your method does not work.

Comment: Does that mean that we cannot apply partial fractions here ?

Comment: Yes, you cannot use partial fractions. Partial fractions are useful when you are dealing with rational functions.

Comment: @JIM: the problem is *not* with partial fractions or rationality of the function. The problem is that the numerator is not a constant, but the term $t$. Try $A\,t/(1+\sin t)+\cdots$.

Comment: It is not clear that making $A$ and $B$ dependent on $t$ would help the OP compute the integral. I wouldn't suggest this method at all. Integration  by parts is the best method.

Comment: @YvesDaoust But I don't think that in partial fractions , It is necessary for the  numerator to be constant .  I have seen integrand having variable in numerator .

Comment: Your mistake was in this step: $\frac{A}{1+ sint}  + \frac{B}{1-sint}   = t.$ Should be: $\frac{At+C}{1+ sint}  + \frac{Bt+D}{1-sint}   =\frac{t}{1-\sin^2 t}$ (denominators on both sides, $t$ in numerators on both sides). Nevertheless, decomposition in 2 fractions is not the best idea in this exercise.

Comment: @JIM Yes, you can get $A$ and $B$ dependent on $t$, but what I am saying that this approach doesn't help you to evaluate the given integral.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy But why is it not applicable only for this integral ?

Comment: @JIM: it *is* applicable but leads you to yet more difficult integrals. And *you* made the mistake of treating the numerator as if it was constant when it is not.

Answer (score 2):

For any real number $x\neq\pm1$, you have$$\frac1{1-x^2}=\frac12\left(\frac1{1+x}+\frac1{1-x}\right)$$and therefore$$\frac1{1-\sin^2t}=\frac{\frac12}{1+\sin t}+\frac{\frac12}{1-\sin t}.$$So,$$\frac t{1-\sin^2 t}=\frac{\frac t2}{1+\sin t}+\frac{\frac t2}{1-\sin t}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution by parts:

Set $u(t)=t,v'(t)=\frac{1}{\cos^2t}.$

Then $u'(t)=1, v(t)=\tan t=\frac{\sin t}{\cos t}$ and

$$\int \frac{t}{\cos^2t}dt=t\tan t-\int\frac{\sin t}{\cos t}dt=t\tan t+\log(\cos t)+c$$